# Output sound to speakers but keep earphones plugged to use microphone

Tags: audio, pulseaudio

I'm trying to use my earphone's microphone (because the computer's built-in is horrible) but output the sound through the computer's speakers.
I've tried to select the output from the sound configurations but it doesn't seem possible, I've tried pavucontrol too but had the same problem.
Running LinuxMint 19.

(The computer is a notebook, with only one jack plug entry)